# Restrict account to only 1 view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL2012.

I have a user and only want them to have select access to a single view and nothing else.

I tried to create my own schema containing the view and deny access to dbo but it seems it doesn't work as I would have expected it to. I can still run queries against tables even though I can't seem them in SSMS.

```
CREATE SCHEMA vl
CREATE VIEW vl.vw_Search AS SELECT 'This is a test' AS RESULT
GRANT select ON vl.vw_Search TO vlu
DENY SELECT On SCHEMA::sys To vlu
DENY SELECT On SCHEMA::INFORMATION_SCHEMA To vlu
DENY INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON schema::dbo to vlu

DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO vlu
DENY VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO vlu
```

I can also still access system views which I also don't want the user to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to see who has access to what:

```
;WITH    perms_cte as
(
        select USER_NAME(p.grantee_principal_id) AS principal_name,
                dp.principal_id,
                dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc,
                p.class_desc,
                OBJECT_NAME(p.major_id) AS object_name,
                p.permission_name,
                p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc
        from    sys.database_permissions p
        inner   JOIN sys.database_principals dp
        on     p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
)
--users
SELECT p.principal_name,  p.principal_type_desc, p.class_desc, p.[object_name], p.permission_name, p.permission_state_desc, cast(NULL as sysname) as role_name
FROM    perms_cte p
WHERE   principal_type_desc <> 'DATABASE_ROLE'
UNION
--role members
SELECT rm.member_principal_name, rm.principal_type_desc, p.class_desc, p.object_name, p.permission_name, p.permission_state_desc,rm.role_name
FROM    perms_cte p
right outer JOIN (
    select role_principal_id, dp.type_desc as principal_type_desc, member_principal_id,user_name(member_principal_id) as member_principal_name,user_name(role_principal_id) as role_name--,*
    from    sys.database_role_members rm
    INNER   JOIN sys.database_principals dp
    ON     rm.member_principal_id = dp.principal_id
) rm
ON     rm.role_principal_id = p.principal_id
order by 1;
```

It is likely the account in question is a member of some role, such as `db_datareader` which is giving it the ability to query other tables.  By default, accounts do not have the ability to access *anything*.